# How to get absolute paths for Quasar Framework files?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, router, quasar-framework, quasar

When i use some route like:

```
http://localhost:8080/patients
```

quasar framework works properly, but when i was try

```
http://localhost:8080/patients/create
```

Not render anything, the cause is because quasar try to get *app.js* from relative path. So return this error in console:

**GET http://localhost:8080/patients/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)**

See than app.js is next to patients.

How i can use app.js like an absolute path for can access in subfolder style url's?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you configured for the `vueRouterMode` property? What command are you running to start the server on port 8080?

Comment: Thanks for comment, but i use `quasar dev`, not `quasar serve`, i have in vue router `mode: 'history'`

Comment: You should set the `vueRouterMode` in your `quasar.conf.js`